# Melt datafarame with certain order in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

I am trying to melt this dataset:

```
raw1 <- c("Alpha", "2018-04-01", "566.0", "647.75", "669.08", "673.08", "675.00")
raw2 <- c("Alpha", "2018-04-02", "563.3", "651.08", "670.67", "684.58", "671.17")
mydf <- as.data.frame(rbind(raw1, raw2))
names(mydf) <-  c("name", "date", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5")
mydf

  name       date    h1     h2     h3     h4     h5
Alpha 2018-04-01 566.0 647.75 669.08 673.08 675.00
Alpha 2018-04-02 563.3 651.08 670.67 684.58 671.17
```

By using:

```
mynewdf <- melt(mydf, id.vars = c("name","date"), variable.name = "hour", value.name = "desiredName", measure.vars = names(mydf[,3:7]))
mynewdf
```

I get:

```
    name       date hour desiredName
1  Alpha 2018-04-01   h1       566.0
2  Alpha 2018-04-02   h1       563.3
3  Alpha 2018-04-01   h2      647.75
4  Alpha 2018-04-02   h2      651.08
5  Alpha 2018-04-01   h3      669.08
6  Alpha 2018-04-02   h3      670.67
7  Alpha 2018-04-01   h4      673.08
8  Alpha 2018-04-02   h4      684.58
9  Alpha 2018-04-01   h5      675.00
10 Alpha 2018-04-02   h5      671.17
```

But I would like to get:

```
      name       date hour desiredName
Alpha 2018-04-01   h1       566.0
Alpha 2018-04-01   h2      647.75
Alpha 2018-04-01   h3      669.08
Alpha 2018-04-01   h4      673.08
Alpha 2018-04-01   h5      675.00
Alpha 2018-04-02   h1       563.3
Alpha 2018-04-02   h2      651.08
Alpha 2018-04-02   h3      670.67
Alpha 2018-04-02   h4      684.58
Alpha 2018-04-02   h5      671.17
```

I have tried to arrange by "hour" but R does not recognize any order in this variable. Should I declare it as factor with order? Any way to arrange in the desired way directly from melt function?

THanks

Comment: `mynewdf[order(mynewdf$date),]` does the trick but I would like to obtain the dataframe ordered with the melt in a way that the first, second third... columns of an id. are melted in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I understood your question well. Adding below code leads to desired output.

```
mynewdf %>% dplyr::arrange(date, hour)
```

[image]